# Ignore/No-use cluster for certain rules

Tags: snakemake

If I am using the --cluster and --cluster-config, is there a way I can designate certain rules to be run in the main snakemake job and not submitted to the cluster as its own job? I have a few rules that are very simple and would not benefit much from cluster execution. In fact they wouldnt even have the required wildcards for the '__default__' cluster-config.

Edit: I would like ask too if using cluster, will invoking python code with 'run' also be executed on the cluster? (I suppose I could test this, but I figure I could tack this in too)

Comment: You could use the 'localrules' keyword to specify rules that execute on the host node and are not submitted to the cluster. The run keyword would invoke python code on the cluster. However, you would need to make sure python is installed on each node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'localrules' is exactly what I am looking for. I completely missed it in the documentation.

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#local-rules

Thank you!